# How to atomatically post data when any new item add in recycler view

Tags: java, android

I am trying to post data when any new Item add in recycler view it automatically post

I have already tried on item click it working fine but i want to post automatically when any item add in recycler view

```
class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    public ArrayList<String> songNames;
    Context context;
    //    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    boolean wasPlaying = false;
    Handler seekHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable run;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> songNames, Context context) {
        this.songNames = songNames;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View listItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.record_card, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(listItem);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.textView.setText(songNames.get(position));


        holder.textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.playerCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                boolean connected = false;
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    //we are connected to a network
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Internet is working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    connected = true;

                    postingData(position, holder);

                    if (connected == true ) {

                    }

                }
                else{

                    connected = false;
                    Toast.makeText(context, "net not", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        });

        holder.cardView1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.playerCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();



        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(CallRecoding.songs.get(position));
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        holder.seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        holder.seekBar.setTag(position);

        holder.seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        holder.seekBarHint.setText("0:00/" + calculateDuration(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));

        holder.playsong.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    holder.pauseRec.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.playsong.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.playsong.setText(" Pause ");
                    run = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Updateing SeekBar every 100 miliseconds
                            holder.seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                            seekHandler.postDelayed(run, 100);
                            //For Showing time of audio(inside runnable)
                            int miliSeconds = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                            if (miliSeconds != 0) {
                                //if audio is playing, showing current time;
                                long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(miliSeconds);
                                long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(miliSeconds);
                                if (minutes == 0) {
                                    holder.seekBarHint.setText("0:" + seconds + "/" + calculateDuration(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
                                } else {
                                    if (seconds >= 60) {
                                        long sec = seconds - (minutes * 60);
                                        holder.seekBarHint.setText(minutes + ":" + sec + "/" + calculateDuration(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                //Displaying total time if audio not playing
                                int totalTime = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                                long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(totalTime);
                                long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(totalTime);
                                if (minutes == 0) {
                                    holder.seekBarHint.setText("0:" + seconds);
                                } else {
                                    if (seconds >= 60) {
                                        long sec = seconds - (minutes * 60);
                                        holder.seekBarHint.setText(minutes + ":" + sec);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    };
                    run.run();
                } else {
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    holder.pauseRec.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    holder.playsong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.playsong.setText(" Play ");
                }
            }
        });


        holder.pauseRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mediaPlayer.pause();
                holder.playsong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.pauseRec.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });


    }



    private void postingData(final int position, final MyViewHolder holder) {

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        final String value = preferences.getString("user_id", "0");
        String currentTime = preferences.getString("currentDate", "1");

        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sp.getString("prospectNumber", "0");

        System.out.println("pressssss"+name);

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                .addFormDataPart("file", songNames.get(position),
                        RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/octet-stream"),
                                new File(CallRecoding.songs.get(position))))

                .addFormDataPart("user_id", value)
                .addFormDataPart("file_name", "Call Recording")
                .addFormDataPart("creation_datetime", currentTime)
                .addFormDataPart("prospect_number","1234567891")
                .addFormDataPart("call_type","incoming")
                .build();

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://159.65.145.32/api/file/upload/")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();


        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                } else {
                    String json = response.body().string();
                    System.out.println("FileUploading >>> " + json);


                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return songNames.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView textView, seekBarHint;
        TextView playsong, pauseRec;
        public static SeekBar seekBar;
        CardView playerCard, cardView1;
        ImageView recdonpost,notdone;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_item);
            playsong = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recplay);
            seekBarHint = itemView.findViewById(R.id.songDur);
            seekBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
            playerCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.playerCard);
            cardView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout1);
            pauseRec = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recPause);

        }


    }

    private String calculateDuration(int duration) {
        String finalDuration = "";
        long minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(duration);
        long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(duration);
        if (minutes == 0) {
            finalDuration = "0:" + seconds;
        } else {
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                long sec = seconds - (minutes * 60);
                finalDuration = minutes + ":" + sec;
            }
        }
        return finalDuration;
    }


}
```

Here is my Recycler view adapter code

I want to post automatically data when data will add in recycler view

Answer (score 0):

When you updating **songNames** in your adapter just match difference and post data for items which are new in the list

Comment: Any another way to do this

Comment: It is best way to do that in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a method like this in your adapter.

```
void addItem(String songName){
   datas.add(songName); // Add new Item into the data list in your Adapter.
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And call this on the activity like this:

```
adapter.addItem(name);
```

Then, it will automatically changes.

Answer (score 0):

You need separation of concerns.

1. Your RecyclerView and Adapter is part of your view component. It should not have any logic regarding network callbacks.
2. If you want to make a request when a new item is added, please check where you are adding the item to the list and calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`. Ideally, your app should make the network call there (or before adding the item to the list).
3. When you do this, the code would have the exact items that are being added so you would make an API call for that. Depending on `bind` method is not reliable as it gets called multiple times when user scrolls the list.

Comment: Can you please show me an example that how can wright my code